# How to extend a continuous function and keep set of maximal

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let $A$ be a compact metric space, $B$ be a compact subset of $A$, and $f$ be a continuous function on $B$.

Is there a continuous function $g$ on $A$ such that

1. $f$ and $g$ agree on $B$, and
2. for each $a \in A \setminus B$, $g(a) < \max\limits_{b \in B} g(b) = \max\limits_{b \in B} f(b)$, that is, the maximal of the extension $g$ cannot be obtained outside $B$?

It would be much better to have an explicit form of $g$. Thanks.

Comment: What's argmax here?

Comment: $\mathop{\operatorname{arg max}}\limits_{a \in B} f(a)$ is the set of points (subset of $B$), at each of which the function $f$ achieves the maximal in $B$.

Answer (score 0):

For question $1$ the answer is yes: use Urysohn's Lemma.

For question $2$ we can construct something explicitly by observing that $B$ is compact in the metric space $A$ and so is closed and bounded.

So, let $b_0 \in B$ be any point of $B$ and consider that $B-b_0 := \{b: b+b_0\in B \}$ contains the origin $0$.  Then any point $a \in A$ lies on a unique line connecting it to the origin, which lies in $B$, and so intersects $B$ at a boundary point.  Call this point $c$.

Then set $$g(a) :=  f(a) \mbox{ if } a\in B $$
and
$$ g(a) := \max \{ (\mathrm{dist}(a,B-b_0)+1)\cdot f(c), \sup_{a\in B} f(a)\} $$ otherwise.  (Note that the $\max$ works because $B\subseteq A$ and so no point in $B$ can be larger than the $\max$ already.)

Comment: Thanks. We do not assume $A$ or $B$ to be convex. So how to identify $c$?

Besides, we want to find an extension $g$ such that the maximal of $g$ cannot obtain outside of $B$.

Comment: I haven't assumed that either.  $c$ is the intersection of the ray $0a$ with $\partial B$, as explained in the answer.  If you have more than one such intersection you will be have to more careful describing $f$ as it will need to take into account each proximal boundary section... but then you really ought to specify your $B$ properly.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand $f(a):=b \text{ if } a \in B$. The function $f$ is already fixed.

Comment: @jiangzhuxing My mistake, I wrote $f$ where I should have had $g$.  I've fixed that now

Comment: Thanks. In the construction of $g$ outside $B$, $\mathop{\operatorname{arg max}}\limits_{a \in A} f(a)$ is not well-defined. Do you mean $\mathop{\operatorname{arg max}}\limits_{a \in B} f(a)$? Besides, how to compare the number $(\text{dist}(a, B-b_0)+1) \cdot f(c)$ and the set $\mathop{\operatorname{arg max}}\limits_{a \in A} f(a)$?

Comment: Ah I see you've clarified $\arg \max$ now!  I thought it was a value, not a set of points.  I shall replace $\arg \max$ with $\sup$